# Duplicate a row on a form

Tags: c#, forms, visual-studio, class

I have a form which initially has one row of boxes for user input. I have a button which, when clicked, should create an identical row below the previous. The button should be able to be clicked more than once, to add multiple rows.

How can I go about implementing this, in a way which gives each control in each row its own unique name (so I can refer to it in my program), and also keeping proper formatting of the rows?

I have tried to set up a class for rows as below:

```
class SubjectRow
{
  //every row has these boxes, plus some more textboxes
  public ComboBox subjectBox;
  public Label maxBox;
  public TextBox aBox;

  public SubjectRow(ComboBox _subjectBox, Label _maxBox, TextBox _aBox)
  {
    subjectBox = _subjectBox;
    maxBox = _maxBox;
    aBox = _aBox;
  }
}
```

...But I am stumped on how to have the button generate the new controls with their own names. My idea was something like this:

```
buttonClicked
{
  SubjectRow row1 = new SubjectRow(subjectBox1, maxBox1, aBox1);
}
```

But I need a way to change the control names here without manually typing them all out; there could possibly be *a lot* of rows on the form.

Is there a way to add more rows to my form using a button, giving each control in each row a unique name? This needs to be done in some kind of loop.

Comment: Do you want a control that is like a table?

Comment: I think that would work, yes. But, for reasons, I am required to use a class somewhere in the program, so I would like to keep the `SubjectRow` class if possible.

Comment: Can't it be done using DataGridView?

Comment: @Nemo go [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview(v=vs.110).aspx).